# NameError: name 'score' is not defined

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

> if  score <
> driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/blockquote[@class='success']/strong"):
> NameError: name 'score' is not defined

How to avoid this error?

```
while True:
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form[1]/blockquote[@class='success']/p[@class='center'][2]/a").click()
 Score = 8,363
 if  score < driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/blockquote[@class='success']/strong"):
     break
```

Comment: You have defined `Score` but not `score`. Make sure both have the same case. I'm guessing you want `score = 8,363`.

Comment: In addition, `find_element_by_xpath` returns a WebElement and not the text of said WebElement so you may want to rethink your comparison.

Comment: `Score = 8,363` is assigning a tuple to the variable - that's unlikely to be something that can be meaningfully compared to the result from `.find_element_by_xpath()`.

Comment: so how do i change this as text driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/blockquote[@class='success']/strong"):  so that it compares with the score?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to know for sure due to the lack of a URL to test against, but you want something like this:

**EDIT**: added code to replace comma in string

```
score = 8363
score_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/blockquote[@class='success']/strong")
score_element_text = score_element.text
score_element_text = score_element_text.replace(',','')
if score < int(score_element_text):
    #do something...
```

If `score_element.text` is displayed with a comma, i.e. 8,300 then you will need to strip that comma first before doing the `if statement` comparison

Comment: when i added your code it gave me this error: if score < int("score_element.text"):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'score_element.text'

Comment: what is the value of `score_element.text`?  Print that out and see

Comment: if score <  ("5,670,000)"):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'str'  its giving me this error

Comment: ok, that's what I was saying in my original answer.  You need to replace those commas in the string.  I updated the answer to reflect that